# Usage of 'contre' in 'Votre courrier a été distribué à son destinataire contre sa signature'

Tags: sens, usage, prépositions

The question is rather simple. Why 'contre' is used in the following sentence?

> Votre courrier a été distribué à son destinataire **contre** sa signature (suivi d'une lettre recommandée).

[I understand the desired meaning.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this seems rather counter (contre?) intuitive, doesn't it? :)

The semantic link you're missing is that of **reciprocity**. An action earns a reaction. A delivery earns a confirmation.

In  [the WordReference entry](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/contre), the closest definition to the one used here is the fourth: "for, in exchange for":

> *Je donnerais dix ans de ma vie contre une bonne santé.*

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that of an exchange; "contre", in this usage has the following meaning.

> ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contre)) III.− Marque l'échange, le rapport de deux grandeurs.
> Échanger un sac de billes contre un couteau; parier à dix contre un

In English this meaning could be rendered by "in return for". The word does not make explicit that the signature is absolutely necessary.